# OP_SHA256 mismatch!

Tags: script

I am new to bitcoin. When I use this online ['Script Execution'](http://webbtc.com/script) site, to calculate the SHA256 hash of 1, I get **4bf5122f344554c53bde2ebb8cd2b7e3d1600ad631c385a5d7cce23c7785459a**
but using any other online calculator you get a different result **6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b**
So probably OP_SHA256 is not what I think, or something happens to input after 1 is pushed into stack.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your conflict is caused because you are hashing different values in the two situations.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha256("1").hexdigest()
'6b86b273ff34fce19d6b804eff5a3f5747ada4eaa22f1d49c01e52ddb7875b4b'
```

Your online tools are showing the hash of the string "1".

```
>>> hashlib.sha256("\x01").hexdigest()
'4bf5122f344554c53bde2ebb8cd2b7e3d1600ad631c385a5d7cce23c7785459a'
```

Bitcoin script stack elements are bytes, for `OP_1` this is `01`.

Comment: @AdrianCousot I suggest marking it as the answer.

Comment: @PandaLion98 New users have to wait 8 hours to accept an answer. So he could do it now, but not then.

Comment: Many thanks , I don't have enough rep to vote you