# What am I doing wrong when calculating the BitCoin Base58 Private Key?

Tags: private-key, node.js

I have this:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const bs58 = require('bs58')

const a = crypto.randomBytes(32)
const b = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(a).digest('hex')
const c = '80' + b
const d = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(c).digest('hex')
const e = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(d).digest('hex')
const f = c + e.substr(0, 4)
const bytes = Buffer.from(f, 'hex')
const address = bs58.encode(bytes)
console.log(address)
```

Which was inspired from [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8247/how-can-i-convert-a-sha256-hash-into-a-bitcoin-base58-private-key/91321#91321). But when I do this:

```
 bitcoin-cli importprivkey "<key>" "foo"
```

I get this:

```
error code: -5
error message:
Invalid private key encoding
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OP\_SHA256 mismatch!](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/40924/op-sha256-mismatch)

Comment: I don't understand what that is saying :/

Comment: @Anonymous I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Did you intend for `a` to be the private key or for it's hash `b` to be the private key?

Comment: @PieterWuille They are hashing the output of tohex(). It’s at least one of the problems.